# How Browserify Fits In - Beginner

Tags: javascript, browserify, ampersand.js

I'm reading a very interesting [article on Ampersand.js](http://silvdb.github.io/2015/04/20/ampersand-js-in-a-nutshell/). Seems like a very cool take on `backbone.js`

Under the *ampersand-view* section, it has a snippet of code that states you can use browserify and I have no clue how browserify would fit in, in this scenario.

var AmpersandView = require('ampersand-view');

```
var ProfileView = new AmpersandView.extend({
    // A View template is not more than a string of HTML. 

    *******
    RIGHT HERE --->>> // You can add in a hardcoded string, use a function that returns a template, or use something like Browserify.
    *******

    // Please do make sure the template only has one root element, otherwise it won't be rendered! 
    template: "<div> <span data-hook='name'></span> <span class='email'></span> <a data-hook='edit'>edit</a> </div>",
    // Bind state to DOM element.
    bindings: {
         ...and so forth
```

What does it mean *"or use something like browserify"*. I think I understand browserify's purpose but I'm not sure how it would fit in here. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Perhaps in this context browserify would return a template. I'm new to and I'm thinking of browserify as something you would do at the highest level and not injected into a smaller portion of the app. Maybe browserify has special template syntax so the author is merely commenting that it's ok to use other frameworks together with ampersand.

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick, browserify _is_not_ about templating! Please read at least something about it (e.g. the official site on the very top says "Browserify lets you require('modules') in the browser by bundling up all of your dependencies.").

Answer (score 0):

Ampersand.js is *designed* in a way to work with browserify (or some other dependency-handling tool, e.g. Webpack), because it consists of CommonJS modules. I'm not sure it would work with the `import` introduced in ES6, but in any case, you want to bundle all your javascript in a single file (or at least in several of them). I'm not sure how you see why browserify was created, but bundling several modules is the purpose of its existence (and then you can do other stuff as well, if you want).

P.S. You haven't wondered where that `require` comes from?